# Script не работает в смартфонах

Tags: javascript

Ниже представлен скрипт, работающий не во всех смартфонах. А имеенно: 
IPhone 5,6, Android 4.4, Galaxy - не работает;  Требуется внести правки.

```
let play = document.querySelector('.play');
// создаем объект AUDIO
const audio = new Audio();

// сразу выставляем уровень звука на средний
let volume = .5
audio.volume = volume;

// присваиваем объекту AUDIO трек
audio.src = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175395/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb';

// показываем какой уровень выставлен
document.querySelector('.vol').innerHTML = audio.volume * 10;

// функция для понижения уровня звука 
document.querySelector('.volume-down').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.volume !== 0) {
    volume -= .1;
    // метод .toFixed() нужен для того чтобы убрать 
    // все лшние цифры кроме первой после точки
    audio.volume = volume.toFixed(1);
    document.querySelector('.vol').innerHTML = audio.volume * 10;
    audio.muted = false;
  }
});
document.querySelector('.volume-up').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.volume !== 1) {
    volume += .1;
    audio.volume = volume.toFixed(1);
    document.querySelector('.vol').innerHTML = audio.volume * 10;
    audio.muted = false;
  }
});

// функция для полного отключения звука
document.querySelector('.mute').addEventListener('click', () => {
  audio.muted = audio.muted == false ? true : false;
})


// функция для запуска и паузы музыки
play.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    play.classList.add('fa-pause');
    play.classList.remove('fa-play');
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    play.classList.remove('fa-pause');
    play.classList.add('fa-play');
  }
})

<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!--кнопка запуска плеера она же и пауза-->
<button class=" play fa fa-play"></button>
<!--кнопка понижения  звук-->
<button class="volume-down">-</button>
<!--кнопка повышение звука-->
<button class="volume-up">+</button>
<!--уровень звука-->
<span class="vol"></span>
<!--кнопка отключения звука-->
<button class="mute">Mute</button>
```

Comment: Объясните что именно не работает. Какие ошибки?

Comment: @Alexandr Tovmach  при нажатии на "плэй" не происходит ничего. Тесты: Андроид 4.4, Айфон 5, Айпад.

Comment: Остальные кнопки рабтают?

Comment: @Alexandr Tovmach Каким образом я могу протестировать остальные кнопки, если не происходит пуск?

Comment: оберните все функции в try-catch и выведите сообщения об ошибках в дом-модель, тогда можно будет примерно понять в чем ошибка, без подключения отладчика непосредственно к девайсу

Comment: Вы компилирует свой код, или запускаете как есть? Возможно проблема в отсутствии поддержки ES6?

Comment: Возможно в тех браузерах нету поддержки некоторых методов - https://caniuse.com/

Comment: @ФаготКоровьев, у меня на тел установлены вот эти браузеры https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser.beta     https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.fennec_aurora     https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome  и везде все работает

Comment: Прости, у  нет `iPhona`  и `Samsung`

Comment: @Air проблема решена. Тревога (с моей стороны) ложная. Всё дело в том, что некоторые пользователи умудряются отлючать поддержку скриптов (или продавцы "подсказывают"), чтобы "экономить трафик/батарею/карму, и т.д. Да, такое, оказывается, носит почти массовый характер. Может, только в нашем регионе? Не знаю. У нас люди особенные, как сказал Мединский, "с лишней хромосомой" большинство.